# Get path of config xml in a package

Tags: java, xml, path, package

Here is my hierarchy :

```
([] <- package)

Java Resources
-> src
    -> []config
       ->profile.xml
    -> []metier
       ->[]profile
          ->ProfileManager.java
...
```

I need to get the path of "profile.xml in ProfileManager.java.

I do this :

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse( new File( "config/profile.xml" ) );
```

But this path is wrong.

How can I do that?

Comment: When you compile,  where are the classes files deployed? And the rest of the project files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file is present in classpath, use `getResourceAsStream` to read it:

E.g.:

```
Document document = builder.parse( ProfileManager.class.getResourceAsStream("/config/profile.xml" ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

try using

> "../../config/profile.xml"

path instead as the path you are using will search the file in same directory as your java file

Comment: Thank you but It doesn't work :
java.io.FileNotFoundException